# You can't change configuration 'providedRuntime' because it is already resolved

Tags: gradle

I am using Gradle 2.0 with Groovy 2.3.3.
When I run the build below I get the error `> You can't change configuration 'providedRuntime' because it is already resolved!`

Other [posts](http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/custom_provided_configuration_not_working_with_gradle_2_0_rc2_in_multi_project_mode) and [release notes](http://gradle.org/docs/2.0/release-notes#+=-operator-changes-that-typically-affect-configuration-of-eclipse-and-idea-plugin) suggest that it is to do with `+=`, however, I'm not using that operator so I am a bit confused.

```
apply plugin: 'war'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

//We don't want transitive dependencies added as we are matching a third-party build
configurations.all {
    transitive = false
}

war  {
    archiveName='gradle.war'

    from(configurations.providedRuntime.files) {
      into "app-jars"
    }
    classpath fileTree('webinf-libs') // adds a file-set to the WEB-INF/lib dir.
}

dependencies {
  providedRuntime group: 'com.thoughtworks.xstream', name: 'xstream', version: '1.4.2'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing war configuration to:

```
war  {
    archiveName='gradle.war'

    from(configurations.providedRuntime) {
      into "app-jars"
    }
    classpath fileTree('webinf-libs') // adds a file-set to the WEB-INF/lib dir.
}
```

will solve the issue.

The problem occurred because `files` was called in `war` configuration block and *then* dependencies were added to *providedRuntime*. Since calling `files` resolves the configuration (and `war` block is evaluated at configuration phase) it can't be modified later on.

You can also change order of `dependencies` and `war` and it will be the same.